# Remove child elements with certain attribute value

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to filter out some children elements, but I'm not managing to iterate throught children properly. Whats wrong in my code:

```
$("#filter").on("click", function() {

        $("div#results > div").each(function () {
            if(!$(this).attr('subcategory', 0)){
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).attr('subcategory', 0)` will set the value to attribute. try this:

```
$("#filter").on("click", function() {
$("div#results > div").each(function () {
if($(this).attr('subcategory')==="0")){
            $(this).remove();
        }
});});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [attribute not equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/)

```
$("div#results > div[subcategory!=0]").remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why go for `.each()` loop go for [attribute-not-equal-selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/):

```
$("#filter").on("click", function() {
    $('div#results > div[subcategory!="0"]').remove();
});
```